# Python 2.4 Doesn't Load Home-Directory Packages

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to get a Python package to install to my home directory because I don't have the privileges to install it system-wide.

The package is PyProj, and I am trying to install it using `python setup.py install --home=~` (with Python 2.4.3), as recommended in the Python documentation. The package compiles successfully and copies itself to what I assume are the correct directories (the directory `~/lib64/python/pyproj` appears during install).

But, when I load Python up and type `import pyproj`, I'm told `ImportError: No module named pyproj`.

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set `PYTHONPATH` to tell Python where to locate your locally installed packages.

For example:

```
[you@home]$ export PYTHONPATH="~/lib64/python"
```

Or, to do this within the interpreter (or script):

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser("~/lib64/python"))
```

For more information on how Python locates installed modules, see section on [The Module search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) in docs.

Comment: What am I setting PYTHONPATH to?

Comment: stw_dev above, seems to have beaten you to the punch as far as an answer goes, but I can't accept it because his answer has a problem, as does yours. Both of you suggested using `sys.path.append("~/lib64/python")`, but I don't think shell expansion works in this command, so you should note, in your answer, that an absolute path is required. Otherwise, things seem to be working now.

Comment: added `.expanduser` to do shell expansion.

Answer (score 2):

`~/lib64/python/pyproj` is not part of your `PYTHONPATH`. There are two or three ways around this, depending on your needs.

The first is to directly modify the path in your module, suitable if you're only going to use it from one module. As noted in the comments, this method does not do expansion on the '~' character.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/username/lib64/python')
import pyproj
```

The second way is to add `~/lib64/python/pyproj` to your system's PYTHONPATH, through whatever method your system suggests. A line in `.bash_profile` is shown below.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/lib64/python/pyproj
```

See the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for more details.

Comment: Your answer was pretty complete, and I especially liked your suggestion to use `sys.path.append`, since I am using this on a web server and prepping the environment would be difficult. However, I discovered, in testing it, that sys.path.append does not do shell expansion on the `~` character, so you should note, in your answer, that an absolute path is required.

Comment: @Richard, Modifying `sys.path` at runtime is fragile and not recommended. Modifying an environment variable for a single process is not an especially invasive task, and is by far the preferred way to do this operation.

Comment: @Mike, could you expand on why this is fragile?

Comment: @Mike, although I'm interested in the generalities of why it is fragile. I wonder if you think it is more fragile than specifying the environment variables from within PHP prior to an exec call?

Comment: For elements I was using in my system I'd modify the variable. On one of my web servers, I set the location of application-specific python modules using the sys.path method. Different strokes..

Comment: @Richard, it's fragile because it puts system configuration information within your actual program, rather than giving it to a general, robust program via traditional means like environment variables.